# Windows 10: Inaccessible Boot Device after dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 Installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dell, windows-10

I just got a Dell Inspiron 7580 with Windows 10 pre-installed. I wanted to install Ubuntu so I followed the usual instructions:

- Disabled Secure Boot
- Disabled Fast Startup

I tried to install from a USB stick but the installer could see no disks at all. I then switched from **RAID** to **AHCI**. The installation was completed successfully and everything seemed to work fine.

After the installation I wanted to check the pre-existing Windows 10 installation and selected Windows Boot Manager, only to see the infamous **INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE** screen.

Everything is OK in the Ubuntu installation.

A pre-installed recovery tool from Dell reinstalled Windows 10 but still the INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE message appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: That "possible duplicate" link doesn't even mention the "inaccessible boot device", and the fix from the answer below worked for me on a Dell G3 3590.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My problem was apparently different from the suggested question.

The issue I had was that in AHCI mode, Ubuntu booted and worked normally but Windows did not boot at all. Then I switched to RAID and noticed that Windows booted and worked normally but Ubuntu did not boot at all.

The problem was that I had switched from RAID to AHCI without safe mode in Windows. When I applied the same switch but in safe mode everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For other readers: https://superuser.com/a/1359471/10136 describes the way to make the change without breaking Windows (by booting into safe mode right after the change).

Comment: After much frustration from a reinstall of Windows, this approach fixed my problem too. Thanks!