# "Inaccessible Boot Drive" error for Windows 11 in a Dual Boot setup in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I initially installed Dual Boot with GRUB with Ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS and Windows 10 on 2 different partitions. About 4 months ago my Windows 10 automatically updated to Windows 11. It ran fine most of the time. But 2 times I received the "Inaccessible boot drive" error when I tried to start Windows. The first time, I went to Windows's Startup Repair and it worked.
[image]

After 1 month of working fine, this morning booting into Windows 11 again shows the "Inaccessible boot drive" error. I tried Startup Repair and that did not work.

So I went into Ubuntu, and follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to use Boot Repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image]

I choose Recommended Repair and went thru all of the steps.

Here is [my log](https://pastebin.com/Mh4UQajk).

After restarting and going to Windows the Inaccessible Boot Device error is still there.

I already reviewed these questions but I don't think they relate to my case:

[How to reinstall grub2 after installing Windows 11 (on a dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347055/how-to-reinstall-grub2-after-installing-windows-11-on-a-dual-boot-system-with-u)

[Windows 10: Inaccessible Boot Device after dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158175/windows-10-inaccessible-boot-device-after-dual-boot-ubuntu-18-04-installation)

Comment: I don't understand if you mean Ubuntu or Linux as is Linux.

Comment: boot-repair won't fix this problem.  That's because GRUB is already handing off to Windows successfully. We know this because you are showing us a Windows error screen. GRUB is not the problem here and GRUB is doing what it's supposed to.  This is a Windows problem. You should ask about this on SuperUser.

Comment: @ThunderBird sorry I mean Ubuntu. Fixed! Any ideas on this?

Comment: @Nmath thanks let me do that. Just a quick question, if I choose the option reset in Windows (re-install Windows but keeping personal files and folders), it won't mess up the dual boot configuration right? The worst thing that could happen is I can no longer log into Ubuntu after resetting Windows.

Comment: We can't really answer Windows questions here, but in general, installing operating systems is not risk-free.  Something could go wrong or you could make a mistake. Windows also historically ignores other installed operating systems and tends to overwrite things like boot preference.  Windows 11 is also still very new and because of the TPM and secure boot requirements there are lots of anecdotal reports of W11 installs messing up Ubuntu boot. You should always have backups which make it easy to get your system set back up if you need to do a clean install.